# On the Stack Exchange main page, site icons should have tooltip summaries

Tags: feature-request, design, tooltips

The page [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) shows all the Stack Exchange sites with icons and relative sizes.

But unless you click into a site, you don't know its purpose. 
 It would be nice if, for example, hovering over ServerFault you would see the tooltip "Q&A for system and network administrators".
I know you can click and get a pop-up, but find that is pretty obtrusive as compared to a simple tooltip.  This is for quickly scanning the sites, not clicking one by one.

Comment: On the top right of the list, there are two buttons, which allow you to change into a "list view" instead of a "grid view". This will display all the descriptions to allow for quick scanning.

Comment: .. or go to https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid